# Mac OS X Linux Unix version

Tags: linux, macos, mac, unix

What Linux or Unix version underlies Mac OS, OS X 10.6?
Is there a good documentation for that version, specifically regarding security, networks and similar topics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Darwin**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29) is at the core of Mac OS X. There is documentation of it scattered all over the net, but I've yet to find a good central location that has it all.

A good starting point is [**Apple's Open Source**](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/) pages.

Answer (score 5):

MacOS X uses Apple's Darwin system as a base.  Darwin uses parts of FreeBSD but massively diverged in many areas so you can't really give version numbers or such.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS is mainly based on FreeBSD.
But of course, there is a considerable amount of proprietary code base on top of it. Especially the kernel, besides the user-land, has been heavily modified.

As for documentation, you can check these two books:
[Mac OS X Security](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735713480) and [OS X for Hackers at Heart](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1597490407)

I haven't personally read these books, but I was told they were OK.

PS: The TCP/IP stack is one of the areas that have been modified to a lesser extent. The changes are mostly in the data link interfaces, so Mac OS practically inherits a lot from FreeBSD on the TCP/IP stack.

Comment: FreeBSD is just a small part of it, the Kernel is a MACH-kernel unrelated to  FreeBSD. Aqua, quartz and all that are custom stuff.